# Tracking skipped steps using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large table with lots of "ORDERS" that go by numbers, each has multiple numbered "STEPS" (not necessarily equal in all orders). Each step has a "STATUS" Which is one of two: "In process" or "completed".
The rule says that in every order, a step must not be marked as completed if steps above him are still in process, and if this is the case, it is a crime that must me found.
Well, I am trying to create a "SKIPPING" column that marks all the skipped steps in each order.

I tried this formula (cell D2)
`=IF($C2="completed","",IF($A2=$A3,"skipped",""))`

**GIVEN TABLE:** (First row and column are belong to Excel's bar)

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **ORDER number** | **STEP number** | **STEP Status** | **SKIPPING** |
| 2 | 179 | 001 | completed |  |
| 3 | 179 | 002 | In process | skipped |
| 4 | 179 | 003 | completed |  |
| 5 | 179 | 004 | completed |  |
| 6 | 192 | 001 | In process | skipped |
| 7 | 192 | 002 | completed |  |
| 8 | 192 | 003 | completed |  |
| 9 | 192 | 004 | In process | skipped |
| 10 | 192 | 005 | In process |  |
| 11 | 202 | 001 | In process | skipped |
| 12 | 202 | 002 | completed |  |
| 13 | 202 | 003 | completed |  |
| 14 | 202 | 004 | In process | skipped |
| 15 | 202 | 005 | In process | skipped |
| 16 | 202 | 006 | In process |  |

The problem with this formula, as shown, is in the steps after the last step marked completed in each order - It marks some that should not be considered skipped (for example in order 202, steps 004 and 005 should not be marked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about the following formula in `D2`:
`=IFERROR(IF(@C:C<>"completed",IF(LARGE(IF((A:A=A2)*(C:C="completed"),ROW(C:C)),1)>ROW(),"skipped",""),""),"")`
It looks for the max row number of the completed status of that order and if the status step status is different then completed it checks if the row number is larger then the latest completed status. The IFERROR is for if no completed status is present for the order.
[image]

This is the version used in the app version of Excel. You may have to use it as an array function (`ctrl+shift+enter`) in other Excel versions and skip the `@`, like so:
`=IFERROR(IF(C2<>"completed",IF(LARGE(IF((A:A=A2)*(C:C="completed"),ROW(C:C)),1)>ROW(),"skipped",""),""),"")`
(Entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`)

Comment: I skipped ```@```  and used it as an array function like so:  ```{=IFERROR(IF(C:C<>"completed",IF(LARGE(IF((A:A=A2)*(C:C="completed"),ROW(C:C)),1)>ROW(),"skipped",""),""),"")}``` but "skipped" was shown in rows 2-4, 6-7, 11-12.

Comment: Did you paste in row 2? It works with me, see screenshot in edit.

Comment: I changed the range `C:C` into `C2` in the second formula to make sure.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Had to read this a few times to understand what you need. Assuming I understand, this works if you have a version or Excel with FILTER().

```
IF(AND(C1 <> "completed", IFNA(MATCH("completed", FILTER(C$1:C1, A$1:A1 = A1)), 0) > 0), "skipped", "")
```

There may be a cleaner solution. If I think of something easier I'll edit my solution.

Here's the explanation:

You want to check for "completed" in Col C for all rows =< the current. Whenever I think of a subset in Excel, the best option is usually FILTER(). This assumes you're running a version of Excel with FILTER().

This finds the set of data for the current order at or above the current row:

```
FILTER(C$1:C1, A$1:A1 = A1))
```

(Some of you will ask why I'm not filtering for "completed" above. I know it's intuitive and seems like the best approach to just use COUNTA() with the set filtered for "completed." However, Excel doesn't have the concept of an empty set and you can't ever get COUNTA() result from FILTER() = 0. It's possible to get this work, but is more complicated than the solution above.)

Once we filter we have an array of all the rows at or above the current row for an order. We don't care what else is in the array, or where it is in the array, just that it exists. Using MATCH() works well.

```
MATCH("completed", FILTER(C$1:C2, A$1:A2 = A2), 0)
```

This returns a number > 0 when "completed" is found in the filtered set and "N/A" when it's not found. So we use IFNA() to return a 0 when it's not found.

```
IFNA(MATCH("completed", FILTER(C$1:C2, A$1:A2 = A2)), 0)
```

Finally, we will get back > 0 values on rows with "completed" in Col C, so we want to skip over those. So we AND() those two conditions and return "skipped" if both are true and an empty string if not.

```
IF(AND(C1 <> "completed", IFNA(MATCH("completed", FILTER(C$1:C1, A$1:A1 = A1)), 0) > 0), "skipped", "")
```

Comment: Learned a lot but i dont have the FILTER option. Thanks